# How do I iterate through each google search page using Selenium Python,but its not happening

Tags: python, selenium, testing, selenium-webdriver, automation

I am trying to iterate through each page, but below code is not working for me.

```
pages=driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@id='nav']/tbody/tr/td/a")
print len(pages)
counter=1
for page in pages:
     counter+=1
     page.click()
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: How many iterations did it go through? is it successful in switching from1 to 2 ? and also could you please share the error response here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code will run successfully only for the first time, aka it will click on the 2nd page and then it will throw a [Stale Element Reference Exception](https://docs.seleniumhq.org/exceptions/stale_element_reference.jsp) on this line -

```
page.click()
```

Now, why is that? Its because the `page` WebElement is nothing but a member of the `pages` list of your elements which you identified *before* clicking once. Since after clicking the pagination button once, the DOM has *changed* ,the reference to the element you earlier located no longer holds significance.

To solve this, you need to *keep finding* the pagination button again and again everytime the DOM changes i.e. everytime you click on the pagination buttons. A simple solution would be to use your `counter` variable to iterate through your list. Here is the complete code -

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'//path to driver')
driver.get("google url")
driver.find_element_by_id("lst-ib").send_keys("search")
driver.find_element_by_id("lst-ib").send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
driver.maximize_window()
pages=driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@id='nav']/tbody/tr/td/a")
counter=1
for page in pages:
     pages=driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@id='nav']/tbody/tr/td/a")
     counter+=1
     pages[counter].click()
```

An alternate (and better) solution would be to identify the pagination buttons by their text -

```
pages=driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@id='nav']/tbody/tr/td/a")
counter=2  #starting from 2
for page in pages:
     driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[text() = '" + str(counter) + "']").click()
     counter+=1
```

You could also, try to press the 'Next' button:

```
pages=driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@id='nav']/tbody/tr/td/a")
counter=2  #starting from 2
for page in pages:
     driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[text()='Next']").click()
     counter+=1
```

**EDIT -**

I fixed your final code. I renamed some variables so that you don't get confused and replaced your implicit waits with [explicit waits](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html).

```
import unittest
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

class GoogleEveryFirstLink(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'D:\Test automation\chromedriver.exe')
        self.driver.get("http://www.google.com")

    def test_Hover_Facebook(self):
        driver = self.driver
        self.assertIn("Google",driver.title)
        elem=driver.find_element_by_id("lst-ib")
        elem.clear()
        elem.send_keys("India")
        elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
        page_counter=2
        links_counter=1
        wait = WebDriverWait(driver,20)
        wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"(//h3[@class='r']/a)[" + str(links_counter) + "]")))
        pages=driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@id='nav']/tbody/tr/td/a")
        elem1=driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//h3[@class='r']/a")
        print len(elem1)
        print len(pages)
        driver.maximize_window()
        for page in pages:
            for e in elem1:
                my_link = driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//h3[@class='r']/a)[" + str(links_counter) + "]")
                print my_link.text
                my_link.click()
                driver.back()
                links_counter+=1
            my_page = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[text() = '" + str(page_counter) + "']")
            my_page.click()
            page_counter+=1

    def tearDown(self):
        self.driver.close()

if __name__=="__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: ,I am trying to click every time the first hyperlink of each page of Google for which I am trying.Even I tried yours by doing some modification but its not working..

Comment: @Muddesir the first code i posted works perfectly for me. Note that you have to manually add your driver path and google URL. Other than that what modifications you made? Show me the exact code you ran.

Comment: Again, you are making the same mistake at "e.click()", the "e" is a member of the elem1 list which you found before clicking the first link and hence it will throw the StaleElementReferenceExecption. You should follow the similar approach as you did for pages.

Comment: Its always breaking in the second time and one thing I notice is that for the pagination it's clicking randomly like 4,7,9,11 and hence on. Could you please let me know why it's not working.

Comment: @Muddesir check my final answer

Comment: ,Thanks it worked perfectly just need to do some modification on your shared code.Thank You...Muddesir